# A thick-skulled person

Tags: word-meaning

What does a thick-skulled person mean in AmE?

> **-1-** A person who doesn't listen to other's statements and opinions and does only what they he/she thinks that is correct and believes only their own opinions.
>
> **-2-** A person who understands and learns too slowly.

Comment: While I think _thick-skulled_ is more closely related to #2, I think [_thick-headed_](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/thick-headed) can sometimes mean #1.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple dictionary entries suggest thick-skulled means:

> Having a thick skull; hence, dull; heavy; stupid; **slow to learn**.
>
> dull of apprehension :  **slow to learn** :  insensitive, stupid